# Firestore where query with parameter not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a query that is not working as I expect it to. I have a collection called 'games' that has a number of documents in it.
Each document has an array called 'hiScores' that consists of the results from that round. I would like to query all games for a specific player for example:

```
.where('hiScores.playerName', '==', 'David Lamm')
```

This is not returning anything. I have no problems when querying a top level variable in the document. What have I done wrong?

Database:
[image: db]

```
db.collection('games')
  .where('hiScores.playerName', '==', 'David Lamm')
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    console.log('Davids games:')

    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the hiScores field is an array, not an object.  You can tell it's an array because the first immediate element of the array in the screenshot has index 0.  You're trying to query hiScores as if it's a single object with a single property called playerName.

Firestore doesn't support querying for object properties within within array fields.  If you have an array field, you can only query to find documents where an entire item is present in the array (an [arrayContains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) query).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Doug this is currently not possible in firestore.

You can create a top level array of strings in each game named playerNames[]. Then use the where condition on playerNames  with array_contains.